# Looking for a data container with O(1) indexing and O(log(n)) insertion and deletion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, containers

I'm not sure if it's possible but it seems a little bit reasonable to me, I'm looking for a data structure which allows me to do these operations:

- insert an item with O(log n)
- remove an item with O(log n)
- find/edit the k'th-smallest element in O(1), for arbitrary k (O(1) indexing)

of course editing won't result in any change in the order of elements. and what makes it somehow possible is I'm going to insert elements one by one in increasing order. So if for example I try inserting for the fifth time, I'm sure all four elements before this one are smaller than it and all the elements after this this are going to be larger.

Comment: k is literally a random number, I'm picking an element randomly, and do some actions with it. I may or may not want to delete that element after I'm done.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a data structure exists. Generally, you have trade offs for each of the different types of data structures and what you've described is a disproportionately powerful data structure. I'm sure if such a thing existed it would be much more prevalent than heaps/trees/etc. If removal time could be made less important, you could use a simple array (which has O(1) appending and O(1) find kth element). I'll keep giving it some thought, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: I can think of `O(logn)` insert+remove & `O(logk)` find k - but I am short on time for detailed answer. The idea is to create an AVL tree with 3 modifications: (1) maintain `min` - a pointer to the min element. (2) maintain the `father` field for each node. (3) maintain `numberOfSons` field for each node. Now, when you need the kth element, start from min, and go your way up, while using `numberOfSons` to know how much elements you have already passed. You will need to go up at most `O(logk)` nodes, and later go back down `O(logk)` nodes, which results in `O(logk)` find kth element

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There's probably a data structure that does what you want if you state all your assumptions clearly. For example do you really need to insert the elements in increasing order? This can hurt (or help). What is strictly necessary? And why is performance a problem?

Comment: @ninjagecko I'm inserting data in an increasing order since I have to. It's not that I want data to be inserted in such a way, but my input values are always increasing. And performance is important since I might have 10,000 entities in my array, and I need to have real fast random access to each entity. and I'll sometimes need to remove random indexes from my list.

Comment: If your array has only 10000 entries, probably O(log N) requirement for deletion is too strong? You can use a [tiered vector](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/papers/tiered-vector.pdf), which allows really fast indexing, but O(sqrt N) deletion. To find element to be deleted in this tiered vector, you need to maintain other data structure in parallel. It may be a search tree, each node of which is augmented by the number of descendants. Overall, you have O(1) almost instant indexing, O(log N) insertion, and O(sqrt N) deletion.

Comment: To correct my previous comment, I should say that maintaining a search tree to find element to be deleted is not really necessary. A simple binary search in tiered vector is enough. In this case, insertion is also O(1).

Comment: If you really want this data structure, I would suggest posting to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com , since this question is asking for a fairly cutting-edge data structure. Currently existing dynamic arrays may support this, but only for insertions and removals at the end of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if the requested time complexities are possible for such a data container. But here is a couple of approaches, which almost achieve these complexities.

First one is [tiered vector](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/papers/tiered-vector.pdf) with O(1) insertion and indexing, but O(sqrt N) deletion. Since you expect only about 10000 elements in this container and sqrt(10000)/log(10000) = 7, you get almost the required performance here. Tiered vector is implemented as an array of ring-buffers, so deleting an element requires moving all elements, following it in the ring-buffer, and moving one element from each of the following ring-buffers to the one, preceding it; indexing in this container means indexing in the array of ring-buffers and then indexing inside the ring-buffer.

It is possible to create a different container, very similar to tiered vector, having exactly the same complexities, but working a little bit faster because it is more cache-friendly. Allocate a N-element array to store the values. And allocate a sqrt(N)-element array to store index corrections (initialized with zeros). I'll show how it works on the example of 100-element container. To delete element with index 56, move elements 57..60 to positions 56..59, then in the array of index corrections add 1 to elements 6..9. To find 84-th element, look up eighth element in the array of index corrections (its value is 1), then add its value to the index (84+1=85), then take 85-th element from the main array. After about half of elements in main array are deleted, it is necessary to compact the whole container to attain contiguous storage. This gets only O(1) cumulative complexity. For real-time applications this operation may be performed in several smaller steps.

This approach may be extended to a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of depth M, taking O(M) time for indexing, O(M*N<sup>1/M</sup>) time for deletion and O(1) time for insertion. Just allocate a N-element array to store the values, N<sup>(M-1)/M</sup>, N<sup>(M-2)/M</sup>, ..., N<sup>1/M</sup>-element arrays to store index corrections. To delete element 2345, move 4 elements in main array, increase 5 elements in the largest "corrections" array, increase 6 elements in the next one and 7 elements in the last one. To get element 5678 from this container, add to 5678 all corrections in elements 5, 56, 567 and use the result to index the main array. Choosing different values for 'M', you can balance the complexity between indexing and deletion operations. For example, for N=65000 you can choose M=4; so indexing requires only 4 memory accesses and deletion updates 4*16=64 memory locations.

Comment: Insertion is O(sqrt N) in tiered vectors and O(N) in your variants because you use a single array. Where does the O(1) come from?
edit: I guess you're referring to a simple push.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to point out first that if *k* is really a random number, then it might be worth considering that the problem might be completely different: asking for the k-th smallest element, with k uniformly at random in the range of the available elements is basically... picking an element at random. And it can be done much differently.

Here I'm assuming you actually need to select for some specific, if arbitrary, *k*.

---

Given your **strong** pre-condition that your elements are inserted in order, there is a simple solution:

- Since your elements are given in order, just add them one by one to an array; that is you have some (infinite) table *T*, and a cursor *c*, initially *c := 1*, when adding an element, do *T[c] := x* and *c := c+1*.
- When you want to access the k-th smallest element, just look at T[k].

The problem, of course, is that as you *delete* elements, you create gaps in the table, such that element *T[k]* might not be the k-th smallest, but the j-th smallest with *j <= k*, because some cells before k are empty.

It then is enough to keep track of the elements which you have deleted, to know **how many** have been deleted that are smaller than *k*. How do you do this in time at most O(log n)? By using a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) or a similar type of data structure. A range tree is a structure that lets you **add** integers and then **query** for all integers in between *X* and *Y*. So, whenever you delete an item, simply add it to the range tree; and when you are looking for the k-th smallest element, make a query for all integers between *0* and *k* that have been deleted; say that *delta* have been deleted, then the k-th element would be in T[k+delta].

There are two slight catches, which require some fixing:

- The range tree returns the range in time O(log n), but to count the number of elements in the range, you must walk through each element in the range and so this adds a time O(D) where D is the number of deleted items in the range; to get rid of this, you must modify the range tree structure so as to keep track, at each node, of the number of distinct elements in the subtree. Maintaining this count will only cost O(log n) which doesn't impact the overall complexity, and it's a fairly trivial modification to do.
- In truth, making just one query will not work. Indeed, if you get delta deleted elements in range 1 to k, then you need to make sure that there are no elements deleted in range k+1 to k+delta, and so on. The full algorithm would be something along the line of what is below.

---

```
KthSmallest(T,k) := {
  a = 1;  b = k;  delta

  do {
    delta = deletedInRange(a, b)
    a = b + 1
    b = b + delta
  while( delta > 0 )

  return T[b]
}
```

The exact complexity of this operation depends on how exactly you make your deletions, but if your elements are deleted uniformly at random, then the number of iterations should be fairly small.

Comment: assuming `deletedInRange(a,b)` returns in O(log(b-a)), I think selecting algorithm will take something like O(n) in worst cases; and it's worst case is when I want to peek the smallest element while there is only one element not deleted in my array and it's at the end of it.

Comment: Worst case analysis is not necessarily pertinent. I don't have a clear picture of your usage pattern, so I don't know how well this would perform for your usage case. If your concern is worse case then you can use the range tree do to binary search and find the k-th element in O((log n)^2). But I think on average this will be less good than what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Treelist](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html) (implementation for Java, with source code), which is O(lg n) for all three ops (insert, delete, index).

Actually, the accepted name for this data structure seems to be "[order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)". (Apart from indexing, it's also defined to support *indexof(element)* in O(lg n).)

By the way, O(1) is not considered much of an advantage over O(lg n). Such differences tend to be overwhelmed by the constant factor in practice. (Are you going to have 1e18 items in the data structure? If we set that as an upper bound, that's just equivalent to  a constant factor of 60 or so.)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). Insert and removal should be O(log n) and peeking of the smallest element is O(1). Peeking or retrieval of the K'th element, however, will be O(log n) again.

EDITED: as amit stated, retrieval is more expensive than just peeking

Comment: It doesn't allow accessing arbitary `k` in `O(1)` nor remove an element (which is not the head) in `O(logn)`

Comment: I doubt you can also get the kth element in O(logn).

Comment: No, you cannot, as said in the answer. But the title of the question asks for the smallest element, so the answer is relevant

Comment: It asks for kth smallest element, and it still doesn't allow arbitrary removal in `O(logn)` (feel free to explain how you find arbitrary element by its key in `O(logn)` in a heap,if you think I am wrong, I'll be glad to learn!)

Comment: @Miquel "k'th smallest element" not only "the smallest"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible.
However, you can make certain changes in balanced binary trees to get kth element in O(log n).

Read more about it here : [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Using_data_structures_to_select_in_sublinear_time)

Answer (score 0):

Indexible Skip lists might be able to do (close) what you want:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_lists#Indexable_skiplist

However, there's a few caveats:

1. It's a probabilistic data structure. That means it's not necessarily going to be O(log N) for all operations
2. It's not going to be O(1) for indexing, just O(log N)
3. Depending on the speed of your RNG and also depending on how slow traversing pointers are, you'll likely get worse performance from this than just sticking with an array and dealing with the higher cost of removals.

Most likely, something along the lines of this is going to be the "best" you can do to achieve your goals.