# Data Structure for fast position lookup

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

Looking for a datastructure that logically represents a *sequence* of elements keyed by *unique ids* (for the purpose of simplicity let's consider them to be strings, or at least hashable objects). Each element can appear only once, there are no gaps, and the first position is 0.

The following operations should be supported (demonstrated with single-letter strings):

- `insert(id, position)` - add the element keyed by `id` into the sequence at offset `position`. Naturally, the position of each element later in the sequence is now incremented by one. Example: `[S E L F].insert(H, 1) -> [S H E L F]`
- `remove(position)` - remove the element at offset `position`. Decrements the position of each element later in the sequence by one. Example: `[S H E L F].remove(2) -> [S H L F]`
- `lookup(id)` - find the position of element keyed by `id`. `[S H L F].lookup(H) -> 1`

The naïve implementation would be either a linked list or an array. Both would give O(n) `lookup`, `remove`, and `insert`.

In practice, `lookup` is likely to be used the most, with `insert` and `remove` happening frequently enough that it would be nice not to be linear (which a simple combination of hashmap + array/list would get you).

In a perfect world it would be O(1) `lookup`, O(log n) `insert`/`remove`, but I actually suspect that wouldn't work from a purely information-theoretic perspective (though I haven't tried it), so O(log n) `lookup` would still be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of *trie* and *hash map* allows O(log n) lookup/insert/remove.

Each node of *trie* contains *id* as well as counter of valid elements, rooted by this node and up to two child pointers. A bit string, determined by left (0) or right (1) turns while traversing the *trie* from its root to given node, is part of the value, stored in the *hash map* for corresponding *id*.

*Remove* operation marks *trie* node as invalid and updates all counters of valid elements on the path from deleted node to the root. Also it deletes corresponding *hash map* entry.

*Insert* operation should use the *position* parameter and counters of valid elements in each *trie* node to search for new node's predecessor and successor nodes. If in-order traversal from predecessor to successor contains any deleted nodes, choose one with lowest rank and reuse it. Otherwise choose either predecessor or successor, and add a new child node to it (right child for predecessor or left one for successor). Then update all counters of valid elements on the path from this node to the root and add corresponding *hash map* entry.

*Lookup* operation gets a bit string from the *hash map* and uses it to go from *trie* root to corresponding node while summing all the counters of valid elements to the left of this path.

All this allow O(log n) expected time for each operation if the sequence of inserts/removes is random enough. If not, the worst case complexity of each operation is O(n). To get it back to O(log n) amortized complexity, watch for sparsity and balancing factors of the tree and if there are too many deleted nodes, re-create a new perfectly balanced and dense tree; if the tree is too imbalanced, rebuild the most imbalanced subtree.

---

Instead of *hash map* it is possible to use some binary search tree or any dictionary data structure. Instead of bit string, used to identify path in the *trie*, *hash map* may store pointer to corresponding node in *trie*.

Other alternative to using *trie* in this data structure is [Indexable skiplist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist).

---

O(log N) time for each operation is acceptable, but not perfect. It is possible, as explained by Kevin, to use an algorithm with O(1) lookup complexity in exchange for larger complexity of other operations: O(sqrt(N)). But this can be improved.

If you choose some number of memory accesses (M) for each lookup operation, other operations may be done in O(M*N<sup>1/M</sup>) time. The idea of such algorithm is presented in [this answer to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519240/1009831). Trie structure, described there, allows easily converting the *position* to the array index and back. Each non-empty element of this array contains *id* and each element of *hash map* maps this *id* back to the array index.

To make it possible to insert element to this data structure, each block of contiguous array elements should be interleaved with some empty space. When one of the blocks exhausts all available empty space, we should rebuild the smallest group of blocks, related to some element of the trie, that has more than 50% empty space. When total number of empty space is less than 50% or more than 75%, we should rebuild the whole structure.

This rebalancing scheme gives O(M*N<sup>1/M</sup>) amortized complexity only for random and evenly distributed insertions/removals. Worst case complexity (for example, if we always insert at leftmost position) is much larger for M > 2. To guarantee O(M*N<sup>1/M</sup>) worst case we need to reserve more memory and to change rebalancing scheme so that it maintains invariant like this: keep empty space reserved for whole structure at least 50%, keep empty space reserved for all data related to the top trie nodes at least 75%, for next level trie nodes - 87.5%, etc.

With M=2, we have O(1) time for lookup and O(sqrt(N)) time for other operations.

With M=log(N), we have O(log(N)) time for every operation.

But in practice small values of M (like 2 .. 5) are preferable. This may be treated as O(1) lookup time and allows  this structure (while performing typical insert/remove operation) to work with up to 5 relatively small contiguous blocks of memory in a cache-friendly way with good vectorization possibilities. Also this limits memory requirements if we require good worst case complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve everything in O(sqrt(n)) time, but I'll warn you that it's going to take some work.

Start by having a look at a blog post I wrote on [ThriftyList](http://software-and-algorithms.blogspot.com/2012/07/thiftydeque.html).  ThriftyList is my implementation of the data structure described in [Resizable Arrays in Optimal Time and Space](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.9607) along with some customizations to maintain O(sqrt(n)) *circular* sublists, each of size O(sqrt(n)).  With circular sublists, one can achieve O(sqrt(n)) time insertion/removal by the standard insert/remove-then-shift in the containing sublist followed by a series of push/pop operations across the circular sublists themselves.

Now, to get the index at which a query value falls, you'll need to maintain a map from value to sublist/absolute-index.  That is to say, a given value maps to the sublist containing the value, plus the absolute index at which the value falls (the index at which the item would fall were the list non-circular).  From these data, you can compute the relative index of the value by taking the offset from the head of the circular sublist and summing with the number of elements which fall behind the containing sublist.  To maintain this map requires O(sqrt(n)) operations per insert/delete.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds roughly like Clojure's persistent vectors - they provide O(log32 n) cost for lookup and update. For smallish values of n O(log32 n) is as good as constant....

Basically they are **array mapped tries**.

Not quite sure on the time complexity for remove and insert - but I'm pretty sure that you could get a variant of this data structure with O(log n)  removes and inserts as well.

See this presentation/video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey

Source code (Java): https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java

Comment: I love Clojure's vectors, but they don't optimize for the most important operation, which is **from** value **to** index. (From index to value is indeed O(log_32 n), but I need the inverse.) As far as I know, that operation (value -> index) is O(n). :-(